# JavaScript atan2() function not giving expected results

Tags: javascript, coordinates, atan2, radians, polar-coordinates

Normally, polar coordinates go from 0 to *π* to 2*π* (just before 2*π* really, as it equals 0 again). However, when using the JavaScript `atan2()` function, I'm getting a different, weird range:

```
Cartesian X | Cartesian Y | Theta (θ)
===========================================================
     1      |      0      | 0 (0 × π)
     1      |      1      | 0.7853981633974483 (0.25 × π)
     0      |      1      | 1.5707963267948966 (0.5 × π)
    -1      |      1      | 2.356194490192345 (0.75 × π)
    -1      |      0      | 3.141592653589793 (1 × π)
    -1      |     -1      | -2.356194490192345 (-0.75 × π)
     0      |     -1      | -1.5707963267948966 (-0.5 × π)
     1      |     -1      | -0.7853981633974483 (-0.25 × π)
```

As you can see, after it reaches *π* (180°), it jumps down to –*π* (–180°), and proceeds back up to 0. How can I get it to use the range **{0, ..., 2*π*}** instead of **{–*π*, ..., *π*}**? I've been trying to think of every calculation to "fix" the values, but I would also like to know why JavaScript chooses this range instead of the typical polar range. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty standard for `atan2` to return angles in that range; for instance, that's what the `atan2` in the C standard library does.

If you want 0..2pi instead of -pi..pi, test whether the result is negative and add 2pi if it is.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct only because it answered my question as to "why" (it's standard). I guess I'll just have to deal with that idiosyncrasy. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. There's really nothing any more idiosyncratic about using the range -pi..pi than there would be about 0..2pi. In fact, arguably it makes more sense, because it puts the discontinuity along the negative x-axis rather than the positive x-axis, which is often sensible. For instance, atan2(y,x) is more or less the same thing as the imaginary part of log(x+iy), and you really want that to be defined (and continuous) when x+iy is positive and real.

Answer (score 7):

It's `atan2(y, x)` not `atan2(x, y)`

Comment: Oh god...Took me an hour to resolve my error...Thank you! Why would anyone create an API like that? Is there any reason for this order?

Answer (score 4):

If the result is negative just add `2 * PI` to the result.

```
function atan2Normalized(x,y) {
    var result = Math.atan2(x, y);
    if (result < 0) {
        result += (2 * Math.PI);
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: @GarethMcCaughanq - you're right - I knew that, but just typed it wrong.  I've corrected it.

Comment: Thank you! This will definitely help. I could also use a conditional (or whatever the technical term is), like `theta_fixed = (theta > 0) ? theta : (theta + 2 * Math.PI);`

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get it to use the range {0, ..., 2π} instead of {–π, ...,
>   π}?

The [`Math.atan2(Y,X)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) function will give different results for `-0` than for `0`.

For example, where `Math.atan2(0, -1)` returns `3.141592653589793`, `Math.atan2(-0, -1)` returns `-3.141592653589793`.

You can use this fact to simplify the equation for getting a result in the range of `[0, 2π)`.

Notice what you get if you negate the `X` and `Y` values:

```
   X   |   Y   |  -X   |  -Y   |  Math.atan2(-Y,-X)
===========================================================
   1   |   0   |  -1   |  -0   | -1.00π (-3.141592653589793)
   1   |   1   |  -1   |  -1   | -0.75π (-2.356194490192345)
   0   |   1   |  -0   |  -1   | -0.50π (-1.5707963267948966)
  -1   |   1   |   1   |  -1   | -0.25π (-0.7853981633974483)
  -1   |   0   |   1   |  -0   |  0.00π (0)
  -1   |  -1   |   1   |   1   |  0.25π (0.7853981633974483)
   0   |  -1   |  -0   |   1   |  0.50π (1.5707963267948966)
   1   |  -1   |  -1   |   1   |  0.75π (2.356194490192345)
```

If you then add `π` to the result, you will get a value in the range `[0, 2π)`.

Therefore you can use:

```
var theta = Math.atan2(-Y, -X) + Math.PI;
```