# How do you read the rotation of a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I have a spinning wheel that I need to read the rotation for. It spins and stops, then I need to read the rotation to know how many points to assign to it. ([the wheel with point values on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8qma.png)). How would I do this? I would think that it would be `document.querySelector(".container").style.transform.rotate` but it returns NaN.

This is the code I'm using to rotate the wheel.

```
var spinInterval = 0;
function timeSpin() {
  var loop = setInterval(function () {
    let spin = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    spinInterval += spin;
    let rotate = `rotate(${spinInterval}deg)`;
    document.querySelector(".container").style.transform = rotate;
    // console.log(rotate);
    rotation = spinInterval;
  }, 100);

  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(loop);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: um, isn't the end rotation just the last spinInterval?

Comment: No it is not. It has a transition property of 5s on the container. This allows for smooth movement but the rotation value doesn't keep up unfortunely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply access the final rotation in the callback of the outer setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(loop);
  // inline style.transform
  console.log(document.querySelector(".container").style.transform);
}, 5000);

// rotate(2279deg)
```

Alternatively
You can use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to return the full computed transform matrix. You'll need to parse it from there.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(loop);
  // full computed transform matrix
  const rotation = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".container")).getPropertyValue('transform');
  console.log(rotation);
}, 5000);

// matrix(-0.7880107536067242, -0.6156614753256553, 0.6156614753256553, -0.7880107536067242, 0, 0)
```

A rundown of the math on CSS-Tricks:[Get Value of CSS Rotation through JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) or in this answer: [How to get CSS transform rotation value in degrees with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574171/how-to-get-css-transform-rotation-value-in-degrees-with-javascript)

```js
var spinInterval = 0;
function timeSpin() {
  var loop = setInterval(function () {
    let spin = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    spinInterval += spin;
    let rotate = `rotate(${spinInterval}deg)`;
    document.querySelector(".container").style.transform = rotate;
    // console.log(rotate);
    rotation = spinInterval;
  }, 100);

  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(loop);
    console.clear();
    // inline style.transform
    console.log(document.querySelector(".container").style.transform);

    // full computed transform matrix
    const rotation= window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".container")).getPropertyValue('transform');
    console.log(rotation);
  }, 5000);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', timeSpin);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 8px solid yellow;
  border-left: 8px solid lightgray;
  border-top: 8px solid aqua;
  border-bottom: 8px solid pink;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
<button type='button' >Spin</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I couldn't have figured that out without the window.computedStyle()

Comment: Note that getComputedStyle returns the local CSS transform; it does not apply all the transforms along the ancestral chain of elements.  I wish there were a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This may get easier with the [CSS Typed Object Model API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Typed_OM_API) (still a draft), but meanwhile you need to look at `style.transform` and parse it manually.  If you know it's just a rotation as above, you could use the following:

```js
parseFloat(/rotate\(([0-9.]+)deg\)/.match(document.querySelector(".container").style.transform)[1])
```